# How to sort a list or dictionary in django?

Tags: python, django

here is the view which contains a dictionary of stores which contains the following info as

```
dictionary = []

       for store in stores:
                            store = Store.objects.get(StoreName=store) 
                            ids = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=productobj , store__StoreName=store).values_list('store__id' , flat=True).distinct()
                            price = StoreProduct.objects.filter(product=productobj , store__StoreName=store).values_list('price' , flat=True).first()
                            distance = StoreLocation.objects.user_store_distance(user_lat , user_long , store.storelocation.latitude , store.storelocation.longitude)
                            dictionary.append({ 'store' : store , 'ids' : ids , 'price' : price , 'latitude' : store.storelocation.latitude , 
                                                'longitude':store.storelocation.longitude , 'distance':distance})

                        print dictionary

                        dictionary = sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x:x['distance']) 

                        print dictionary
```

And then displaying the above data in the table ..here is the template

```
<table class="wrapper storetable" onload="showmore()">

                    <tr  class="text-center" id="tablehead"><td style="width: 70px"></td><td>Store Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Distance</td>
                    <td>Sort<br><select id="sort_table"><option>Relevance</option><option>Distance</option><option>Price</option></select></td></tr>

                    {% for item in ProductStores %}                 
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td style="width: 70px; font-size:20px"><a href="#" data-lat="{{item.latitude}},{{item.longitude}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMapModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                        <td>
                            {{ item.store }} <br> {{ storeproduct.store.MallName }}
                        </td>
                        <td> Rs. {{ item.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.distance}} Kms.</td>

                        <td>
                            <button class="button" type="Submit" id="addtocart" onclick="getCart(event,{{ product.id }} , {{ minId }})">ADD TO BAG</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

How can i sort the above by price and distance ? ie from low to high price and then low to high distance

here is some sample data which returns the same result after applying the sorting it returns the same result.

```
[{'distance': '100.79', 'price': 2100L, 'ids': [1L], 'longitude': u'77.2090', 'latitude': u'28.6139', 'store': <Store: DOROTHY>}, {'distance': '91.71', 'price': 2100L, 'ids': [4L], 'lo
ngitude': u'77.29275380000001', 'latitude': u'28.63642', 'store': <Store: Dorothy Perkins PV>}]
[{'distance': '100.79', 'price': 2100L, 'ids': [1L], 'longitude': u'77.2090', 'latitude': u'28.6139', 'store': <Store: DOROTHY>}, {'distance': '91.71', 'price': 2100L, 'ids': [4L], 'lo
ngitude': u'77.29275380000001', 'latitude': u'28.63642', 'store': <Store: Dorothy Perkins PV>}]
```

Comment: Something with the indent doesn't feel right. Do you really return with render after first iteration ? Second, dictionnary doesn't suport ordering. I suppose you want to order dictionary (ProductStores in data), is this correct ?

Comment: You can simply use sorted() method which is provided by Python core library.  ex: sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x:  x["distance"])

Comment: return is outside the loop yes.

Comment: how is that thing going to sort the distance ...by low to high ? high to low ?

Comment: yes i want to order ProductStores@ArthurHavlicek

Comment: Could you add these models and functions you have used as well. May be we can see if ordering is possible from the queryset itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should consider renaming your variable **dictionary** to something that resembles a list. Now, I am assuming that you want to sort your **dictionary** by price. If that is correct you can use following:

```
dictionary = sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x:x['price'])
```

This will be in ascending order of price, to make it descending use

```
dictionary = sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x:x['price'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: does the same goes by for distance as well?

Comment: @AdityaSingh yes just replace price with distance

Comment: Nothing happens i am getting the same output as before sorting out

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying to sort plus some sample data if thats possible for you.

Comment: First of all, the price key in your dictionary has a orm query against it, which returns ValuesListQuerySet, something like [1, 5]. I think what you want there is int/float type of data and that to one price value per store.

Comment: i want to sorted the data coming according from low to high for price and distance

Comment: @AdityaSingh the data against the key price is either of type long or its a very long integer, you can see the trailing 'L' after 2100 in your sample data, once i take that out and run my solution against your sample data it works

Comment: But distance is perfect ...doesnt work there...100.79 is coming before 91.71

Comment: @AdityaSingh you distance key has a string values '91.71', '100.79'